# Set Isolation Level in stored procedure: will it work before define stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm dealing with legacy code and trying to normalize it to same standard and my question do you think #1 READ UNCOMMITTED will work for given procedure? My tests showed so, but have some doubts. Main goal to free resource so all possible should be UNCOMMITTED.

I assume #2 definitely is OK and is best practice even it's inside `BEGIN TRY`  not just `BEGIN`

```
USE Alpha
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED    --#1 will it work for sp_Test ?? 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]  
AS  
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT  
        CASE transaction_isolation_level
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Read / Uncomitted 1'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted 1'
           ELSE 'UNKNOWN 1'
        END AS transaction_isolation_level_name
    FROM
        sys.dm_exec_requests  
    WHERE 
        session_id = @@spid
 --  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED    --#2

   SELECT TOP 1 cust_id 
   FROM readOnly..table 

   UPDATE dbo.test 
   SET c1 = 'x'        -- will this UPDATE kill Read Uncomitted ?

   SELECT  
       CASE transaction_isolation_level
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Read / Uncomitted 2'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted 2'
           ELSE 'UNKNOWN 2'
        END AS transaction_isolation_level_name
    FROM 
        sys.dm_exec_requests  
    WHERE 
        session_id = @@spid
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

It's a property of your session rather than of a procedure. The procedure will use whatever the calling session already has, unless you override it within the procedure.

Setting everything to READ UNCOMMITTED though is a big red flag. Unless you don't care about data consistency, you really don't want to do that. You can miss data, you can have duplicated data, etc. There's a reason it's not the default, and there are usually other ways to address whatever issue causes you to want to use it.

Comment: @MarioTrento, be aware that dirty reads can mean rows duplicated or missing entirely from results, not just reading uncommitted data.